# Difference between HTML block elements and CSS display block property

Tags: html, css

May I know if there is any difference between HTML block elements (Eg. `<p>`, `<div>`,...) and CSS property `display: block`?

Since from what I have read they are the same, but why we still need to use `display: block` for some block level element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: It's the same. Block elements are block because they have `display: block` as default styles. Nothing more. We can say that `span` with `display: block` is the same as `div` (both with zero semantic value).

Comment: http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

Comment: You are starting from a false assertion. We do **not** need to use `display:block` on block level elements **unless** the property is being **reverted** to that state after being changed previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call "HTML block elements" are elements who have their display property set to `block` so there is no difference between a `<div>` and a `<span>` with `display:block;`.

This display property is set by the user agent stylesheet (i.e your browser). You can view these properties in chrome dev tool under "user agent stylesheet".

The only reason I see of using `display:block;` for a `div` element is :

- your target adience is using some obscur user agent that don't follow web stadards (very unlikely)
- you need to override a previous CSS declaration like `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between... because block elements already have default css property `display: block`. 
 
But we use `display: block` to show them again, when we hide/remove them from page using `display: none`.