# Block-level HTML elements and CSS Specification default value of display property

Tags: html, css

This shows that "display" is initially "inline" for all elements:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#the-display-properties

However, this says "(and assuming the DIV and the P both have 'display: block')":
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level

I did see this question that shows that the browser sets the default display value.
[Difference between HTML block elements and CSS display block property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457357/difference-between-html-block-elements-and-css-display-block-property).

**Q.** How does this reconcile with the CSS Spec. statement that "display" is initially "inline" for all elements? Does the CSS specification statement about "initially inline" refer to the state before the browser sets `display:block` for block-level elements?

Comment: Specification != implementation

Answer (score 1):

> Does the CSS specification statement about "initially inline" refer to the state before the browser sets display:block for block-level elements?

It refers to the default value of a property if nothing is defined including any browser default style.

> Each property has an initial value, defined in the property’s definition table. If the property is not an inherited property, and the cascade does not result in a value, then the specified value of the property is its initial value. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#initial-values)</sup>

The fact that you can read "(and assuming the DIV and the P both have 'display: block')" confirms the logic because the Specification is not telling you that `p` and `div` *should be* or *are* block elements but let's assume they are block element for the sake of the explanation that comes next.

> div and p are flow content (WhatWG) and thus presumably have "display: block" by default.

"Flow content" and "display: block" are not linked together. Some elements are flow content but they don't have "display: block" like `a`, `span` and many others.

The [content models](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#content-models) has nothing to do with the display value.

Comment: @Coder this is how browser define them by default since too long. It was for sure discussed somewhere and defined to be like that but still it has nothing to do with the "initial" value and it's not contradictory with the Specification. You can start your searching here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascade .. the "User Agent" is what you are looking for. You will probably find the source of such implementation.

Comment: Regarding your statement that flow content is not linked to display:block, this shows that phrasing content is generally inline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233447/what-is-the-difference-between-phrasing-content-and-flow-content 

That was basically what I meant by flow content (non-phrasing) generally being block-level, however I didn't know enough to exactly convey that.